# jQuery remove first and last space on input propertychange

Tags: jquery, client-side-validation

I want to remove first and last space of any input on all the events (keyup/keydown/oncopy/onpaste etc).

I have tried with below code but its not working.

```
 $("body").on("input propertychange", "input", function (e) {               
                if (e.which === 32 && e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
                    return false;
                }
 });
```

Comment: Please do not use [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has absolutely nothing to do with this plugin. Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your HTML :

```js
function trim (el) {
    el.value = el.value.
       replace (/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, ""). // removes leading and trailing spaces
       replace (/[ ]{2,}/gi," ").       // replaces multiple spaces with one space 
       replace (/\n +/,"\n");           // Removes spaces after newlines
    return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter value : <input type="text" name="test_input" onchange="return trim(this)" />
```

Would you please check my above snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `trim()` is what you're looking :
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: no @mickdev, it will even restrict me to enter space between two words..

Answer (score 0):

You should use trim() function of jquery which is useful to remove first and last space. You can get more idea from https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/.

e.g. `$.trim("    hello, how are you?    ");` gives you `"hello, how are you?"` output.